# Multiplication of a list's elements with a specific number within a for loop is returning an empty list as the output

Tags: loops, for-loop

I obtained a list "IR" by using the `IR=Para['Infection Rate'].tolist()` function, where Para is a pandas data frame with "Infection Rate" being one of its columns. IR is `Infection_Rate=[3.1,1.5,1.0,1.1,0.8,0.8,1.0,0.8,1.1,1.1,1.2,1.1,1.8,1.5,2.3,1.2,1.0,1.0,0.8,1.4,1.2,0.9,0.7,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0,0.6,0.9,0.9,1.0,1.4,1.3,1.7,1.3,0.6,1.1,1.1]`

Then I am trying to multiply x with the first element of the list IR, then trying to multiply the product of this multiplication with the second element of the list IR and so on until the second last product is multiplied with the last element of the list IR. To make sure that the product is getting multiplied only to the next element of the list, I am incrementing the iterator "i". However, when I print "y", the output is an empty list. What could be going wrong?

'''

```
x=0.428571
i = 0
y=[]
 
for i in range(len(IR)):
    if(i >= len(IR)):
        break
        
        y=IR[i]*x
        
        i+=1
        
print(y)
```

'''

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there sample of `IR` list and expected output?

Comment: Hi I have made the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edit, I'm supposing you can do desired result with `.cumprod()` panda's method:

```py
x = 0.428571
df.loc[0, "Infection Rate"] *= x  # multiply first element by `x`
print(df["Infection Rate"].cumprod())
```

Prints:

```
0      1.328570
1      1.992855
2      1.992855
3      2.192141
4      1.753713
5      1.402970
6      1.402970
7      1.122376

...
```

---

`df` used:

```
    Infection Rate
0              3.1
1              1.5
2              1.0
3              1.1
4              0.8
5              0.8
6              1.0
7              0.8
8              1.1
9              1.1
10             1.2

...
```

Comment: Hi, it totally worked. Thank you.